# Copy conditional formating for another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I currently have a dashboard where I can change the currency from EUR to USD and I've setup a conditional formating rule to change the color to green is the value is >0 and red if the value is <0. If we take the example below, cells B2 would be green but need A2 to also turn green. I can set each cell manually to copy the B cell but that would take ages in my case.

```
A1 | B1
$  | 12
€  | -12
$  | 0
```

Are there any easy ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Range: `A1:B3`

Formula for green: `=$B1>0`

Formula for red: `=$B1<0`

[image]

Adapt to your case.

Comment: I've tried your solution but but I can't get it quite right. This is what it looks like on my screen: https://i.imgur.com/SA1dsPj.png

Comment: There are merged cells so that is not clear in which cell are actual values you want to compare to. Could you share sample sheet with manually colored cells of desired result?